# Why is "escaping" a participle here?

Tags: adjectives, gerunds, participles

The Cambridge Dictionary says:

> In English, many past and present participles of verbs can be used as adjectives. Some of these examples may show the adjective use.

*So there is no **escaping** from it: scientific language has to be tackled and mastered if scientific thought is to be followed.*

*From the Cambridge English Corpus*

*The negative approach is to defend it by showing that it represents one way of **escaping** a number of problems facing standard egalitarian justification.*

*From the Cambridge English Corpus*

Isn't *escaping* a gerund, however, in both the examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So there is no **escaping** from it: scientific language has to be tackled and mastered if scientific thought is to be followed.

"No escaping from it" is a what Huddleston & Pullum (2002) refer to as a Hybrid Construction. It is hybrid in the sense that it is headed by a gerund-participle verb "escaping" but it takes a pre-head dependent that is characteristic of an NP structure, which in this case is the determiner "no".

> The negative approach is to defend it by showing that it represents one way of **escaping** a number of problems facing standard egalitarian justification.

In this case, "escaping" is also a verb in the form of gerund-participle. "Escaping a number of problems" is therefore a VP that functions as complement of "of".

In modern grammar, the distinction between gerund and present participle is discarded entirely. There are a lot of grammars that follow this, such as that of Huddleston & Pullum (2002) and that of Aarts (2014). Huddleston & Pullum (2002) use the compound term "gerund-participle" to replace them both.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @user178049. I'm not entirely well-versed in the CaGEL terminology. But I get your point. Still, if I may ask is *escaping* a gerund or a participle in the examples above in the light of traditional grammar?

Comment: @User40475 I think you misunderstood Cambridge. The statement you found on Cambridge website is just a warning to inform you that many past and present participle verbs can also be adjectives: eg. "Entertaining" is an adjective in "The TV show is entertaining", but a verb in "He is entertaining us". In traditional grammar, "escaping" is a gerund in both of your examples. It is a gerund in the first sentence because it behaves like a noun (takes a determiner). It is a gerund in the second sentence because it is complement of a preposition.

Comment: Above it says _Some of these examples may show the **adjective use**_, and then the examples follow. Now if they're adjectives, they're participles and not gerunds. Because a gerund is a noun, not an adjective @user178049.

Comment: @User40475 Can you give a link. I found the same statement here: https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/angered and here: https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/correlating

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/escaping @user178049

Comment: @User40475 No, you misunderstood. Those examples aren't what they are talking about. As I said, it is just a caveat and the examples have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Ah, I see. _**Some** of these examples **may** show the adjective use_ is what you mean by caveat, right? @user178049.

Comment: Yes, exactly @User40475

Comment: Thank you very much @user178049.